# .Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone error -1004 - Unable to set the pagebreak property

Tags: excel, vba, printing

So I'm trying to reset all manual pagebreaks in my file. Ok, great, a quick google search gets me

```
.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
```

Great, let's throw it in with the worksheet reference

```
shPrintTemp.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
```

and go.

I run my code, and I get "error -1004 - Unable to set the pagebreak property."

Strange. Let me do some more research. I find a few other forum posts with a similar problem, a similar proposed solution, and usually people say it works. However, occasionally someone gets the same error that I'm hitting - and no solution is ever posted.

So I wonder "What if it's just a computer being a computer", and I reset Excel. Same error. Reset my computer. Same error. Try the immediate window, still the same error. Try

```
 Wb.Sheets("Print temp").Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
```

Same error.

I'm at my wits end here.

To prevent the XY problem, what I really want is a way to quickly and cleanly remove all of the manual page breaks in a sheet. (Without nuking and recreating the sheet, because that's starting to sound like an attractive option....). The way I'd like to do it is by debugging the page break line, especially since there doesn't appear to be an answer posted to this problem anywhere online (or easily findable online....) but really, any way would be nice.

Comment: If you are in the Page Break Preview Mode, you must enter the following line before the line above to prevent an error: `ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reset all page breaks by
`Worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks`

(your cases `shPrintTemp.ResetAllPageBreaks` or
`Wb.Sheets("Print temp").ResetAllPageBreaks` will both work)

Comment: Thanks! I also then needed to add a shPrintTemp.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1 to fix the verticle breaks, for anyone else looking for answers